# TypeError: wrapper.props(...).onClick is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

> Foo.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

export default (props) => {
  const { func } = props;
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => func()}>Click</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

> Foo.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme, { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import Foo from './Foo';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('foo test', () => {
  const props = {
    func: jest.fn(),
  };

  test('test foo', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Foo {...props} />)
    expect(wrapper.props().onClick()).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

When i run test coverage it shows `TypeError: wrapper.props(...).onClick is not a function`. According to documentation `jest.fn()` returns a function. My requirement is i need to call `func` on ***Foo.jsx*** 's onClick handler.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To test this scenario, you need to simulate the click event of button, to which you are attaching the prop fund. Because that is supposed to be called only when the click event is triggered on the button.

```
test('test foo', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Foo {...props} />);
    /** here the second argument to `simulate` is the event object, which is not required for your use-case. Still I kept it for future reference, if needed.
**/
    wrapper.find('button').simulate('click', {}); 
    expect(props.func).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

This will call the `func` which was received in props of the component and can be verified via the expectation as set above.